# Cannot generate indexable for a type containing a Map with a custom Key type

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s, circe

I'm using scala 2.11.11, elastic4s 5.4.5 and elastic4s-circe 5.4.5

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.TcpClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

object Test {

  val client: TcpClient = ???

  case class Something(a: Map[AnotherThing, Int])
  case class AnotherThing(b: Int)

  val smth = Something(Map.empty)

  client.execute {
    indexInto("index" / "type").doc(smth)
  }

}
```

This would not compile:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.sksamuel.elastic4s.Indexable[net.lizeo.bd4m.storage.Test.Something]
indexInto("index" / "type").doc(smth)
```

According to the documentation:

> Simply add the import for your chosen library below and then with those implicits in scope, you can now pass any type you like to doc and an Indexable will be derived automatically.

With `import io.circe.generic.auto._`and `import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.circe._` for elastic4s-circe.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using a different json marshaller. You should have no such issues with Jackson for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `case classes` outside the scope of `Test` object i.e. outside the `Test` class. You can define them as separate classes as well.

So correct way should be

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.TcpClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

object Test {

  val client: TcpClient = ???

  val smth = Something(Map.empty)

  client.execute {
    indexInto("index" / "type").doc(smth)
  }

}

case class Something(a: Map[AnotherThing, Int])
case class AnotherThing(b: Int)
```

Comment: it does not work...
And I don't understand why it could work, the problem starts when I put a map with a custom key inside the `Something` case class i.e. if I try to index an `AnotherThing` instance solely, it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Circe, but I used SprayJson and maybe my answer helps future persons looking at this question:

For Spary, I first niavely thought the `import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.sprayjson._` will suffice, but Spray requires a JsonProtocol for the custom case classes, like this:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val smthFormat = jsonFormat1(Something)
  implicit val anotherThgFormat = jsonFormat1(AnotherThing)
}
```

And then you import both at the top of your code:

```
import MyJsonProtocol._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.sprayjson._
```

I think this part of auto-magic is implemented in Circe's `import io.circe.generic.auto._`, but maybe it doesn't work with elastic4s and you have to write it by hand.